# JRuby disabled stack guard

Tags: jruby

I've installed jruby 1.7.4 and every time an program is executed I get the following error:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /opt/jruby/lib/native/arm-     Linux/libjffi-1.2.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
```

I tried to disable the error message with the "execstack -c /opt/jruby/lib/native/arm-     Linux/libjffi-1.2.so" but the error keeps creeping in.

How can disable/fix this error message?

Answer (score 0):

simply install a somehow recent of JRuby 1.7.x ... that is e.g. **1.7.17** at the moment